# Can't run java from PHP's exec

Tags: java, php, linux, shell, jar

I've been trying to run a JAR file that would read from `input.txt` and write to `output.txt` this way in console:

```
java -jar file.jar input.txt output.txt
```

And it works 100% fine on my machine. I need to run it inside a php script, and this code works 100% fine for me (Mac OS, php built-in server):

```
exec("java -jar file.jar input.txt output.txt");
```

But once I deploy it (CentOS server) where the `exec` function is allowed, it fails, it returns an empty string and the jar does not work, running it directly from shell is OK.

How can I fix that? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: does the user the php script is running as have permission to read/write the directory this stuff is in? just because it works for you at the command prompt doesn't mean much. that's a different user, in a much different environment.

Comment: First, I'm not a fan of exec given the security implications. Having said that, try using the full path to the `java` executable and the files in that command and see if that works.

Comment: @MarcB yes, the Apache user is the same as the user under which I executed that from console (on that server) and it worked fine

Comment: how about java? is that in the path of the shell php is using? like I said  - much different environment.

Comment: @PatrickLee I don;'t think I have pretty much options without exec, I'll give a try to full paths!

Comment: @PatrickLee thank you so much, the full path to java worked just fine! Could you please post that as an answer?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I just posted an answer with the same info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your `exec()` is that PHP doesn't know where Java is on the server. Update your command to specify the full path to the Java executable and it should work, though you should also use full paths to the jar and text files while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the path of java with `which` command. Open terminal, run command

```bash
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

2. Use full path to java in a exec command

```php
exec("/usr/bin/java -jar file.jar input.txt output.txt");
```